# Is HMAC-MD5 collision-resistant if the key is unknown?

Tags: hmac, collision-resistance, md5

I'm in a situation where I *need* to use HMAC-MD5 (for a learning, non-production application) and it needs to be collision-resistant.

So my question: **Is HMAC-MD5 collision-resistant if the key is unknown, ie you are only given standard oracle access to an HMAC-MD5 oracle?**

Alternatively, if possible you can replace "MD5" with "any Merkle-Damgård hash function for which collisions are known" (which is a more general statement).

Note that [*"Is HMAC-MD5 still secure for commitment or other common uses?"*](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/25584/23623), while related, only talks about the situation with a *known* key to the adversary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, HMAC-MD5 with the key secret is still considered practically secure against all attacks, including collisions. We are about in the situation considered in Mihir Bellare's [*New Proofs for NMAC and HMAC: Security without Collision-Resistance*](http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~mihir/papers/hmac-new.html) (extended abstract [in proceedings of Crytpto 2006](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/11818175_36)).

But as the saying attributed to the NSA goes: attacks only get better; they never get worse.