# Is HMAC-SHA256 a PRF?

Tags: hmac, sha-256, pseudo-random-function, sha-2

In the abstract of [The Exact PRF-Security of NMAC and HMAC](https://eprint.iacr.org/2014/578.pdf), Gazi, Pietrzak, and Rybar state:

> NMAC was introduced by Bellare, Canetti and Krawczyk [Crypto’96], who proved it to be a secure
> pseudorandom function (PRF), and thus also a MAC, assuming that (1) f is a PRF and (2) the function we get when cascading f is weakly collision-resistant. Unfortunately, HMAC is typically instantiated with cryptographic hash functions like MD5 or SHA-1 for which (2) has been found to be wrong.

This implies that HMAC-SHA1 and HMAC-MD5 are not PRFs. However, I'm not sure whether SHA-2 (particularly, SHA-256) is considered to satisfy (2) from their abstract, and thus whether HMAC-SHA2 (particularly, HMAC-SHA256) is a PRF. I'm further confused by result from [Bellare, 2006](https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/%7Emihir/papers/hmac-new.pdf) which seems to contract the more recent paper by proving that collision resistance of the underlying function is not necessary in order for an HMAC to be a PRF.

Comment: Note that the quoted text only states that the original authors (back in 1996) required collision resistance to prove PRF security.

Comment: That depends on the instantiation, there is a distinguisher for [some](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/88150/18298)

Comment: By "instantiation", I assume you are referring to the underlying CRHF? Is there a distinguisher for SHA-2/SHA-256?

Comment: To prove a PRF is not an easy task, disproving is the easier way. As long as one is not showing, assume that it is.

Comment: Understood; do you know if it is currently assumed by most cryptographers that SHA-256 is a PRF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TLDR: (2) is a sufficient condition, but probably not a necessary condition. Most people would probably believe that HMAC-SHA-1 is indeed a PRF, although SHA-1 is not WCR.

The 2006 paper by Bellare claims to prove that e.g. HMAC-SHA-1 is a PRF, if the *inner compression function* of SHA-1 is a PRF. No known attacks break the pseudorandomness of the inner function, so taken at face value, we would conclude that HMAC-SHA-1 is a PRF.
However, reading that paper closely, this is proven for NMAC, and other two-keyed constructions. The proof for standard HMAC requires a related-key assumption (see Setion 5). This assumption is also pretty mild, and not even close to be broken by any known attack.

So to conclude: In practice, HMAC-SHA-1 is *probably* a PRF. The 2006 Bellare paper identifies relatively mild assumptions under which this holds, but if you want to precisely identify these assumptions, read Section 5 of that paper *carefully*.